# Pygame score issue

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

```
while not done:
    baddieAddCounter = 0
    baddies = []
    score += 1
    fact = ""

    #GIVES PLAYER A NEW FACT EVERYTIME THEY REACH THE TARGET SCORE
    if score < 200:
       fact == 'NOTHING'

    elif score > 200 and score <= 599:
       fact == 'SWAG'

    elif score > 600 and score <= 799:
       fact == 'brehh'


    drawText('Score: %s' % (score), font, screen, 10, 0)
    drawText('Fact: %s' % (fact), font, screen, 10, 40)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Why is this not working? In game, once the players score reaches the target score (ex >200) it's supposed to change the fact (ex. SWAG') to what it says in the 'if' statement but it stays the same because of the 'fact = ""'.

Comment: It should be `fact = 'NOTHING'` not `fact == 'NOTHING'`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not assigning to `fact`, you are comparing it. What I assume you want is

```
if score < 200:
       fact = 'NOTHING'

elif score > 200 and score <= 599:
   fact = 'SWAG'

elif score > 600 and score <= 799:
   fact = 'brehh'
```

Also note, at a score of 200 the player will get a blank fact, as the first condition is only less than 200, and the next is only greater than 200.

Answer (score 0):

You code doesn't set `fact` when score is 200. You have to check `score >= 200` or use

```
if score < 200:
   fact == 'NOTHING'

elif score <= 599:
   fact == 'SWAG'

elif score <= 799:
   fact == 'brehh'
```

BTW: you can set `face=''` before `while`

```
fact = ""

baddieAddCounter = 0
baddies = []

while not done:
    score += 1

   if score < 200:
      fact == 'NOTHING'

   elif score <= 599:
      fact == 'SWAG'

   elif score <= 799:
      fact == 'brehh'

   drawText('Score: %s' % (score), font, screen, 10, 0)
   drawText('Fact: %s' % (fact), font, screen, 10, 40)
   pygame.display.update()
```

**EDIT:**

@Margius has right. You use `==` but you need `=`

```
fact = ""

baddieAddCounter = 0
baddies = []

while not done:
    score += 1

   if score < 200:
      fact = 'NOTHING'

   elif score <= 599:
      fact = 'SWAG'

   elif score <= 799:
      fact = 'brehh'

   drawText('Score: %s' % (score), font, screen, 10, 0)
   drawText('Fact: %s' % (fact), font, screen, 10, 40)
   pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: I have to say: I did not notice '==' until @Margius showed this :)